# Want to edit/PUT/PATCH but error says "No route matches [POST]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building my second-ever basic Ruby on Rails application and having fun doing it, but have gotten stuck at precisely the same place that gave me trouble (and was never solved) on my last effort: the PUT or PATCH request.

My application has two models: entries and users. A logged-in user should be able to edit only those entries that were originally created by that user.

CONTROLLER

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
# authenticate user (Devise)
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
# set entry upon page load
before_action :set_entry, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET request - display all entries
def index
    @all_entries = Entry.all
end

# GET request - display an individual entry
def show
    # nothing required here because entry identified with before_action :set_entry on line 2 above
end

# GET request - access form to create a new entry
def new
    @entry = Entry.new
    @user = User.find(current_user[:id])
end

# GET request - access form to update an existing entry
def edit
    if @entry[:user_id] != current_user[:id]
        redirect_to root_path
    else 
        redirect_to edit_entry_path
    end
end

# POST request - make a new entry/save new data into db
def create
    user = current_user[:id]
    Entry.create({
        entry_title: params[:entry][:entry_title], 
        book_title: params[:entry][:book_title],
        text: params[:entry][:text], 
        img_url: params[:entry][:img_url], 
        tag: params[:entry][:tag], 
        created_at: params[:entry][:created_at], 
        user_id: user 
    })
    redirect_to entries_path
end

# PUT request - save changes to an existing entry
def update
    if @entry.update(entry_params)
        redirect_to entry_path
    else 
        render :new
    end
end

# DELETE request - delete an existing entry from db
def destroy
    @entry.destroy
    redirect_to entries_path
end

private

def set_entry
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
end

def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:email, :text, :tag)
end

end
```

VIEW (show.html.erb - shows a single entry and includes links allowing the logged-in user who originally authored the entry to edit or delete it)

```
<h3>Selected Entry</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>Entry title: <%= @entry.entry_title %></div>
            <div>Book title: <%= @entry.book_title %></div>
            <div>Text: <%= @entry.text %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div><%= @entry.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></div>
            <div>Submitted by: <i><%= @entry.user.email %></i></div>
            <div>File under: <i><%= @entry.tag %></i></div>

            <% if current_user %>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', @entry, :method => 'update' %>
                <%= link_to 'Delete', @entry, :method => 'delete' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ROUTES.RB - At first my routes were the commented-out lines, but then I had a thought that was either madness or sudden realization - should only the GET routes lead with "get"? So that's the non-commented-out attempt you see. Somehow the app works (except for the issue at hand) both ways.

In researching I've come across routes defined using a much more elaborate syntax than that I'm using here. I've been unable to figure out whether a given way of doing things is different convention, outdated, or just inadequate to the task.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :entries

  # root 'entries#index'

  # get '/entries' => 'entries#index'

  # get '/users' => 'users#index'

  # get '/entries/:id' => 'entries#show'

  # get '/entries/:id' => 'entries#update'

  # get '/entries/new' => 'entries#new'

  # get '/entries/:id/edit' => 'entries#edit'

  # get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'

  # get '/about' => 'pages#index'

  root 'entries#index'

  get '/entries' => 'entries#index'

  get '/entries/new' => 'entries#new'

  post '/entries' => 'entries#create'

  get '/entries/:id' => 'entries#show'

  get '/entries/:id/edit' => 'entries#edit'

  put '/entries/:id' => 'entries#update'

  delete '/entries/:id' => 'entries#destroy'

  get '/users' => 'users#index'

  get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'

  get '/about' => 'pages#index'

end
```

Thanks in advance for any insight. If additional context is needed I'm happy to provide.

Edited to add:
PARTIAL (_form.html.erb)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="form-container">
        <%= form_for @entry do |form| %>
            <br>
            <%= form.text_field :entry_title, :size => 59, :placeholder => "Entry Title"%>
            <br><br>
            <%= form.text_field :book_title, :size => 59, :placeholder => "Book Title"%>
            <br><br>
            <%= form.text_field :img_url, :size => 59, :placeholder => "Image URL"%>
            <br><br>
            <%= form.text_area :text, :placeholder => "Text" %>
            <br><br>
            <%= form.text_field :tag, :placeholder => "Tag" %>
            <br><br>
            <%= form.submit %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have both `resources` and individual get/post/etc?

Comment: Remove the individual routes and keep the resource route only. and give your code for edit form.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Guess that's not the way to go and I could just include the `get '/about' => 'pages#index'` in the routes.rb, since that's the only route not handled for me by `resources` or Devise? I understand that in the case of duplication the first instance of a route takes precedence.

If I rake routes in Terminal, the routes related to PATCH and PUT lack related prefixes. I'm working under the impression that these verbs don't need their own views since they involve updating the database.

Comment: Can you post your _form.html.erb partial as well?

Comment: Posted the partial. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a record you

- first, should use a GET request to get the edit form
- second, should submit that form using a PUT/PATCH request

To get to the edit form you should link to the edit path for your entry

`<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_entry_path(@entry) %>`

The Rails form helpers will automatically set the form to submit with the proper method, PUT OR PATCH.

Comment: Also, in your routes `resources :entries` should be sufficient. You can remove all the individual routes which start with '/entries'

Answer (score 0):

`:method` in `link_to` helpers refers to HTML verb (get, post, etc), while controllers methods naming convention is action.

[link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

You need something as

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', @entry, :method => 'put' %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', @entry, :action => 'update' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance you are trying to post with the edit link. Remember new/edit are get methods to render form, so just just delete method part in your links. Like from

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', @entry, :method => 'update' %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_entry_path(@entry) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm building my second-ever basic Ruby on Rails application

Congrats! You need at least 3 more before it all starts to make sense

---

To add to the existing answers, you'll be best looking at the [`resources` directive](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) to clean the routes up:

```
#config/routes.rb
root 'entries#index'
devise_for :users

resources  :entries
resources  :pages,  only: [:index], path_names: { index: "about" }
resources  :users,  only: [:index,:show]
```

--

> A logged-in user should be able to edit **only those entries that were originally created by that user**.

This is known as *authorization*.

- **Authentication** = is user logged in?
- **Authorization** = can user do this?

Although people confuse Devise with being able to handle authorization, it only handles authentication. Whilst you have a simple implementation of this in your controller, you should check out either the [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gems:

```
#Gemfile
gem "cancancan"

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id
  end
end

#app/controllers/entries_controller.rb
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      authorize! :edit, @entry
   end
end
```

--

Finally, to answer your question directly, you're calling the `update` method (which doesn't exist) to access the *edit* view:

```
<% if current_user %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', @entry, :method => 'update' %>
   <%= link_to 'Delete', @entry, :method => 'delete' %>
<% end %>
```

You should read up about [http verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) - this is what the "method" option invokes with the `link`. As mentioned above, you don't need to set the method for `edit` as it uses `GET`. `Update` uses `put/patch`, which I can explain later.

A much better way to achieve what you want would be the following:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_entry_path(@entry) if can? :edit, @entry %>
<%= link_to "Delete", @entry, method: :delete, if can? :destroy, @entry %>
```

The above uses the `CanCanCan` authorization method [`can?`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization)